# Modulated input in cadence

Tags: cadence, frequency-response

I am giving a 25MHz signal input to pll for simulation in cadence. But I also want to modulate its frequencies from 1Khz to 2Mhz. But how to do the frequency modulation of a signal in cadence?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it's good to use VPWL to create piece-wise-linear data, that I just smooth.  This is not as nice as using a frequency source, but it does have the advantage of being able to script something using python or matlab, and then feed that into Spectre.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for: -

```
> VSFFM - Frequency Modulated Sinusoidal Voltage Source Model
```

[image]

Link: https://techdocs.altium.com/ru/display/AMSE/VSFFM+-+Frequency+Modulated+Sinusoidal+Voltage+Source+Model